# Regression confidence on new data point

Tags: regression, prediction-interval, uncertainty

I'm in the process of building a prediction system, and one of its requirements is to be able to give the confidence of a prediction. That is, given a set of independent variables, it should be able to not only give the predicted dependent variable, but also some indication of "confidence".

Classifiers are typically able to return a range between predictions (from 0-1, for instance), which gives you some information about how "confident" the classifier is about a given prediction. In a binary situation, a prediction of 0.51 might denote low confidence, while 0.98 might denote high confidence, given the training set.

Regression changes things a bit, as it is used to predict a continuous variable anyway, rather than a classification. What are commonly accepted methods to determine a given data point's confidence?

Confidence/prediction intervals somewhat accomplish this, but my data has the potential to be very non-normally distributed. Considering just one feature, I could end up with 20 pieces of data around x=50, and only 1 around x=1. I'd expect my bounds to be tighter around x=50, but the CI/PI wouldn't really account for this uneven distribution, as it assumes normality. Is there any way to account for this?

Thanks for any help you can offer, and sorry about the relative airiness of this question!

Comment: So... like a prediction interval for regression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For regression problem, the prediction interval may be what you are interested in, according to your question.

It is the confidence interval of the predicted result of the new data point. In detail, it is the confidence interval of (the fitted reslut of that data point according to your model plus the random error term). So it is a little larger than the confidence interval of the fitted data.

Comment: I slightly edited my post... I am aware that you can use a prediction interval to get general bounds on a set of data, but I'm wondering if you have a non-normal distribution of data, if you can determine the bounds at different regions of the data.

Comment: The answer introduced the general meaning of prediction inverval, which can be applied into any problem. The concept of prediction interval is neither built on assumption of "normal distribution",nor "linear model". But it depends on the model we set case by case. If a non-normal distribution (e.g gamma) is set, the prediction interval presents as our distribution (gamma). Again, not only the linear model could have prediction interval, other non-linear regressions also could have prediction interval.